# JPQL, Can I Create DTO using Constructor which Takes Entities by Selecting All Columns In Once?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I'm using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. I made repository having a method returning `List<AWithBDto>` like

```kotlin
    @Query(
        """
        select new com.test.example.AWithBDto(a.a1, a.a2, ..., b.b1, b.b2, ...) 
        from A a join B b where ~
        order by ~
    """
    )
```

Because I thought **listing all columns of table a and b is tedious**, I added a constructor in AWithBDto as follows. (in Kotlin)

```kotlin
data class AWithBDto(
   ...
) {
    constructor(a: A, b: B) : this(
        a1 = a.a1,
        a2 = a.a2,
        ...,
        b1 = b.b1,
        b2 = b.b2,
        ...,
    )
}
```

So I **could shorten** my repository codes as follows.

```kotlin
    @Query(
        """
        select new com.test.example.AWithBDto(a, b) 
        from A a join B b where ~
        order by ~
    """
    )
```

However, the **query made kind of N+1 problems** because it selected **only id columns** from both tables.

```
        select
            a0_.id as col_0_0_,
            b1_.id as col_1_0_ 
        from
            a a0_ 
        inner join
            b b1_ 
                on a0_.id=b1_.id 
        where
            ~
        order by
            ~
```

and **multiple queries selecting all columns for each single row from each table** were executed.

```
    select
        a0_.id as id1_3_0_,
        ...,
        ...,
    from
        a a0_ 
    where
        a0_.id=?
```

...multiple times

```
    select
        b0_.id as id1_4_0_,
        ...,
        ...,
    from
        b b0_ 
    where
        b0_.id=?
```

...multiple times

In JPQL, Can I create DTO using a constructor which takes entities as params by selecting all columns in once? I **want Hibernate to execute a single query** for this.

Or if I can't, could you **suggest good alternatives** for me?

Comment: If you want to select all columns then why not just select the entire entities?

Comment: Take a look into Spring Data JPA Projection.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(A.class)
public interface AWithBDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getA1();
    String getA2();

    // Either map properties through nested mapping path expressions
    @Mapping("b.b1")
    String getB1();
    @Mapping("b.b2")
    String getB2();

    // Or through a subview
    BDto getB();

    @EntityView(B.class)
    interface BDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getB1();
        String getB2();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`AWithBDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, AWithBDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<AWithBDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!